# how to make multiple objects move automatically

Tags: python, tkinter, animation, canvas

I've been learning python for 3 weeks and I/m making a plane game with a flying plane that must avoid colliding with clouds. I've made the plane move up, down, forward (I also wanted to make the plane rotate up when flying upwards and down when downwards but I'm not that experienced to do that)

My problem now is that I need the clouds to move against the plane and spawn again and again in a loop.

Here is the code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
import keyboard

WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 720
window = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

background_image = PhotoImage(file='sky_background.png')
backg_image = canvas.create_image(0,0,image=background_image,anchor=NW)

plane_image = PhotoImage(file='plane.png')
plane = canvas.create_image(0,165,image=plane_image,anchor=NW)

cloud_image = PhotoImage(file='cloud.png')
cloud = canvas.create_image(600,480,image=cloud_image,anchor=NW)

image_width = PhotoImage().width()
image_height = PhotoImage().height()
       
def move_fwd(event):
    x = 3
    y = 0
    canvas.move(plane,x,y)
    
def move_up_diagonally(event):
    x = 1.7
    y = -3
    canvas.move(plane,x,y)
    
def move_down_diagonally(event):
    x = 1.7
    y = 3
    canvas.move(plane,x,y)

window.bind("<d>",move_down_diagonally)
window.bind("<s>",move_down_diagonally)
window.bind("<d>",move_up_diagonally)
window.bind("<w>",move_up_diagonally)
window.bind("<d>",move_fwd)

    
window.update()
time.sleep(0.1)
```

I tried to bind the move of the cloud on a key that is player using to move the plane.

Answer (score 0):

How about this method ?

```
def cloud():
    while True:
        rand_x = randint(0,WIDTH-100)
        rand_y = randint(0,HEIGHT-400)
        corrector = choice([True, False])
        clouds = []
        step=5
        cloud_size = list(range(1, 1000, step))
        for i in cloud_size:
            resized_img =  cloud_img.resize((i,i))
            cloud_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_img)
            if corrector:
                cloud = canvas.create_image(rand_x-i,rand_y,image=cloud_image,anchor=NW)
            else:
                cloud = canvas.create_image(rand_x,rand_y,image=cloud_image,anchor=NW)
            window.update()
```

This method infinitly draws clouds and resizes them gradualy to give you the impresison it's comming towards you. It places them randomly also and choses wether to correct for the resizing, to avoid the impression it that it is moving towads the right, or not.

You should call it with a seperate thread so as to not to infinitly freeze the window.

```
t= Thread(target=cloud)
t.start()
```

Also I chose to use `PIL` instead of just `tk.PhotoImage`, you can download it by running the command:

```
pip install pillow
```

Here is the complete code:

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 
from random import randint, choice
from threading import Thread
WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 720
window = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

background_image = PhotoImage(file='sky.png')
backg_image = canvas.create_image(0,0,image=background_image,anchor=NW)

plane_image = PhotoImage(file='plane.png')
plane = canvas.create_image(0,165,image=plane_image,anchor=NW)
cloud_img = Image.open('cloud.png')



image_width = PhotoImage().width()
image_height = PhotoImage().height()
       
def move_fwd(event):
    x = 3
    y = 0
    canvas.move(plane,x,y)
    
def move_up_diagonally(event):
    x = 1.7
    y = -3
    canvas.move(plane,x,y)
    
def move_down_diagonally(event):
    x = 1.7
    y = 3
    canvas.move(plane,x,y)

def cloud():
    while True:
        rand_x = randint(0,WIDTH-100)
        rand_y = randint(0,HEIGHT-400)
        corrector = choice([True, False])
        clouds = []
        step=5
        cloud_size = list(range(1, 1000, step))
        for i in cloud_size:
            resized_img =  cloud_img.resize((i,i))
            cloud_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_img)
            if corrector:
                cloud = canvas.create_image(rand_x-i,rand_y,image=cloud_image,anchor=NW)
            else:
                cloud = canvas.create_image(rand_x,rand_y,image=cloud_image,anchor=NW)
            window.update()


t= Thread(target=cloud)
t.start()



window.bind("<d>",move_down_diagonally)
window.bind("<s>",move_down_diagonally)
window.bind("<d>",move_up_diagonally)
window.bind("<w>",move_up_diagonally)
window.bind("<d>",move_fwd)

    
window.update()
window.mainloop()
```

Also I removed the `time.sleep` call, it's not necessary and will just make your game more laggy.

If you want to have multiple instances of the clouds, you just need to wrap it all up with a thread spawner, adjust the `CLOUD_COUNT` variable depending on your system's capabilities.
Here is the code for that:

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 
from random import randint, choice
from threading import Thread
WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 720
window = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

background_image = PhotoImage(file='sky.png')
backg_image = canvas.create_image(0,0,image=background_image,anchor=NW)

plane_image = PhotoImage(file='plane.png')
plane = canvas.create_image(0,165,image=plane_image,anchor=NW)




image_width = PhotoImage().width()
image_height = PhotoImage().height()
       
def move_right(event):
    x = 10
    y = 0
    canvas.move(plane,x,y)

def move_left(event):
    x = -10
    y = 0
    canvas.move(plane,x,y)
    
def move_up(event):
    x = 0
    y = -10
    canvas.move(plane,x,y)
    
def move_down(event):
    x = 0
    y = 10
    canvas.move(plane,x,y)


CLOUD_COUNT = 4
cloud_images=[Image.open('cloud.png') for i in range(CLOUD_COUNT)]

def cloud(index):
    clouds = []
    step=5
    cloud_size = list(range(1, 600, step))
    while True:
        rand_x = randint(0,WIDTH-100)
        rand_y = randint(0,HEIGHT-400)
        corrector = choice([True, False])
        for i in cloud_size:
            resized_img =  cloud_images[index].resize((i,i))
            cloud_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_img)
            if corrector:
                cloud = canvas.create_image(rand_x-i,rand_y,image=cloud_image,anchor=NW)
            else:
                cloud = canvas.create_image(rand_x,rand_y,image=cloud_image,anchor=NW)
            window.update()


def lots_of_clouds():
    threads = []
    for i in range(CLOUD_COUNT):
        Thread(target=lambda : cloud(i)).start()
        

lots_of_clouds()
window.bind("<s>",move_down)
window.bind("<z>",move_up)
window.bind("<d>",move_right)
window.bind("<q>",move_left)
window.update()
window.mainloop()
```

I hope this will be a help to you!